# MySql - Update query optimization

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have large table with 53m rows. I want to enforce unique key. In order to do that i have to find dupe rows and resolve conflicts (nullify some values).

Here is my attempt, and it took over 20 minutes.

```
EXPLAIN UPDATE entry AS e
    JOIN entry AS e_min ON e.race_id = e_min.race_id
    AND e.bib = e_min.bib
    AND e.id > e_min.id
SET e.bib = NULL; 

"id","select_type","table","partitions","type","possible_keys","key","key_len","ref","rows","filtered","Extra"
1,"UPDATE","e",NULL,"ALL","PRIMARY,FK_en_ra__external_id,idx_race_id2,ix_race_id_status_type_team_id,entry_idx_id_status,idx_race_bib",NULL,NULL,NULL,53118893,90.00,"Using where"
1,"SIMPLE","e2",NULL,"ref","PRIMARY,FK_en_ra__external_id,idx_race_id2,ix_race_id_status_type_team_id,entry_idx_id_status,idx_race_bib","idx_race_bib",56,"bazu.e.race_id,bazu.e.bib",1,33.33,"Using where; Using index"
```

[image]

Also i have tried, and it took even longer

```
Explain UPDATE entry AS e
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT race_id, bib, MIN(id) AS min_id
    FROM entry
    GROUP BY race_id, bib
    HAVING count(id) > 1
) AS min_ids ON e.race_id = min_ids.race_id AND e.bib = min_ids.bib AND e.id > min_ids.min_id
SET e.bib = NULL;

"id","select_type","table","partitions","type","possible_keys","key","key_len","ref","rows","filtered","Extra"
1,"UPDATE","e",NULL,"ALL","PRIMARY,FK_en_ra__external_id,idx_race_id2,ix_race_id_status_type_team_id,entry_idx_id_status,idx_race_bib",NULL,NULL,NULL,53118893,90.00,"Using where"
1,"SIMPLE","e2",NULL,"ref","PRIMARY,FK_en_ra__external_id,idx_race_id2,ix_race_id_status_type_team_id,entry_idx_id_status,idx_race_bib","idx_race_bib",56,"bazu.e.race_id,bazu.e.bib",1,33.33,"Using where; Using index"
```

[image]

I have tried to add index, but expecting faster execution time.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_race_bib_id ON entry (race_id, bib, id);
```

Any ideas how to improve query or add some additional indexes are welcomed!

Comment: Please share all details **in text form**

Comment: Is this a one time task, and if not, then how often would you be running it?

Comment: Yes it is one time task, just to enforce unique key

Comment: Added csv explain output.

Comment: If one time then why worry about execution time - it will take longer to analyse and optimise than to run it.

Comment: @P.Salmon it will create deadlock.

Comment: @P.Salmon it takes over 30 minutes.

Comment: Run the update in batches instead of all in one update.

Comment: Provide: complete CREATE TABLE script, precise MySQL version.